# Error in Internet Explorer: ` Invalid character

Tags: javascript

I am testing an app on IE.

I'm having the problem reading the ` character when the (dynamic) table is read.

```js
list.forEach(item=>{
  let child = document.createElement("tr");
  child.innerHTML = `<td>${item.id}</td><td>${item.name}</td><td>${item.password}</td><td>${item.email}</td><td>${item.sex}</td><td>${item.country}</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>`;
  table.appendChild(child);
})
```

If it can be fixed, how can I do this?

Comment: I believe that's ES6 syntax, and IE only supports up to ES5. The solution would be to rewrite the string using ' or " quotes.

Comment: @Tim so instead of ` I should put ' or " ?

Comment: IE11 does not support ES6 syntax and by extension, template literals. You need to use concatenation to construct your string, and it's not just replacing backpacks with `"`, since `${item.name}` will be printed as-is in a normal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE supports ES5.

You will have to rewrite your code.

```
list.forEach(item=>{
  let child = document.createElement("tr");
  child.innerHTML = '<td>'+item.id+'</td><td>'+item.name+'</td><td>'+item.password+'</td><td>'+item.email+'</td><td>'+item.sex+'</td><td>'+item.country+'</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>';
  table.appendChild(child);
})
```